# How to Copy Column and Paste Values to a New Column Every Time Macro Is Initiated

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I have a spreadsheet that calculates variances in column Z. At the end of the month I would like to copy and paste the values into another column in the same spreadsheet to keep track of the variances month to month.

I have a macro to copy from column Z to column BK.

I would like that each time I run the macro, to copy the values from column Z and paste it into a new column using the following schedule:

- Month 1 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BK
- Month 2 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BL
- Month 3 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BM
- Month 4 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BN
- Month 5 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BO
- Month 6 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BP
- Month 7 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BQ
- Month 8 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BR
- Month 9 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BS
- Month 10 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BT
- Month 11 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BU
- Month 12 = Values Should be Pasted in Column BV

After the 12th iteration, I would like the values from column Z to be copied into Column BK (the starting point). I believe this can be done using a loop?

I am having a difficult time coming up with the loop logic/coding.

```
Sub copyCurrentToPrevious()

    Dim ans As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Direct Materials").Activate

    ans = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to copy Previous Month Variance to YTD Variance Tracking?  This action can not be undone." & vbNewLine _
      & vbNewLine & "Select Yes to proceed with the copy/paste operation or Select No to cancel.", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Product Costing")

    If ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Range("Z9:Z220").Copy
    Range("BK9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("Z226:Z306").Copy
    Range("BK226").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("Z311:Z471").Copy
    Range("BK311").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("Z476:Z524").Copy
    Range("BK476").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A1").Select

    MsgBox "Copy / paste operation is complete.  Select OK to continue.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Product Costing"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You're pretty good to go, just use `MONTH` and `OFFSET` together for right column choice. Good luck, and my +1 for the efforts!

Comment: Thanks Peter! Question... But how would that work? Doesn't it need to go through a loop so that it would automatically increment by 1 column each time the macro is run?

Comment: no, just read how the offset works - all you need is shift (which is month number in your case) starting the 1st column BK. You need to replace `Range("BK9")` with `Cells([number], [column BK + offset to the right])`. All the details are in VBA help)

Answer (score 1):

Heres a refactor of your code, adding the required offsets, and addressing a number of other issues:

- use correct data type for `ans`
- don't use `Resume Next`.  What that says is *I don't care if I had and error, just carry on regardless.  Who knows whats going to happen next*
- Don't use `Activate` or `Select` (unless you have a specific need to).  Use `Workbook`, `Worksheet`, and `Range` objects instead.  Note that `Worksheets("Direct Materials")` is implicity saying `Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Direct Materials")`
- you don't actually need to `Copy`/`Paste` for this.  Use the `Variant Array` that `.Value` returns instead.  This will be faster and not vulnerable to interuption by other apps using the clipboard.  Also its a good habit to get into as it's usefull in all sorts of ways.

---

```
Sub copyCurrentToPrevious()
    Dim ans As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo EH

    ans = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to copy Previous Month Variance to YTD Variance Tracking?  This action can not be undone." & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine & "Select Yes to proceed with the copy/paste operation or Select No to cancel.", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Product Costing")

    If ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Direct Materials")
        Set rng = .Range("Z9:Z220")
        rng.Offset(0, Month(Now()) + 36).Value = rng.Value

        Set rng = .Range("Z226:Z306")
        rng.Offset(0, Month(Now()) + 36).Value = rng.Value

        Set rng = .Range("Z311:Z471")
        rng.Offset(0, Month(Now()) + 36).Value = rng.Value

        Set rng = .Range("Z476:Z524")
        rng.Offset(0, Month(Now()) + 36).Value = rng.Value
    End With

    MsgBox "Copy / paste operation is complete.  Select OK to continue.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Product Costing"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox "Something went horribly wrong!"
End Sub
```

Comment: fair +1 for thorough & detailed explanations (were useful for me as well)

Comment: Thanks @chris. So for this to work properly, I will have to run the macro to put the data in January column (BK) some time during the month of January? I just tested it out and the code placed placed the data in the February column... Lets say that I forgot to run the macro during the end of January and it is now February, how can I make sure that the data gets copied to the January month? I appreciate all of your help so far. I am mentioning this to help avoid human error by copying values to the wrong month. Is there a way to ask the user to confirm which column the data is being placed 1st?

Comment: As written the `Sub` will place the data in a column based on todays date.  You could devise other rules, say up to the 10th of the month, place for last month ( `Month(Now()-10)` )  or use a `MsgBox` or `InputBox` to ask the user.

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen . Everything is squared away. I appreciate your help.